# Check if variable values are NULL in DataSet in c#

Tags: c#, dataset

I am trying to iterate through a `DataSet` to check if the variable `Mp.TheObjectPropertyNameMatr` of MasterPage has returned `NULL` values.

When the variable `Mp.TheObjectPropertyNameMatr` of `MasterPage` has returned `NULL` values, I need redirect this aspx page to default aspx page.

But If add on `DataSet` this code:

```
private DataSet RetrieveProducts()
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Mp.TheObjectPropertyNameMatr))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
        ....... 
        return ds;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");     
    }
}
```

I Have this error:

> No executable code

On this line code:

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

Please can you help me ?

Comment: When `return` is getting called your method will get exited immediately (in most cases). So if you want to execute `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");`, you have to move it above the return line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error *"No executable code"* because you are returning `null` **before** `Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");` line.

In your case, Code written after return statement is not reachable.

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return):

> The return statement terminates execution of the method in which it
>   appears and returns control to the calling method.